# Como incluir um campo no dataExporter do PrimeFaces que não existe no dataTable?

Tags: java, java-ee, primefaces

Como incluir um campo no dataExporter do dataTable (Primefaces) que não está na dataTable?

Eu estou gerando um arquivo Excel a partir de um dataTable com dataExporter, mas eu preciso incluir uma coluna que não existe no dataTable.

Este dataTable são itens de um lote e preciso que este número seja colocado numa coluna, mas não gostaria que o mesmo fosse exibido na lista, pois eles se repetiriam.

Como fazer?

Comment: Cara não sei se tem como, uma solução seria colocar os campos no `dataTable` e dar um `rendered="false"` pra eles não serem exibidos.

Comment: Com `rendered="false"` não funcionou.

Comment: Um colega me passou a solução, testei e funcionou. Como fazer? Adicionar normalmente a coluna no dataTable e colocar  `style="display:nome"` depois incluir no dataTable `scrollable="true"`para que não gere colunas em branco no final do arquivo excel gerado.

Comment: Sim, qualquer coisa tente isso também: `<h:outputText value="#{bean.exemplo}" id="exemplo" style="visibility:hidden;">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marcelo, talvez já tenha encontrado a solução, mas vou deixar aqui um exemplo.

Dada uma dataTable qualquer do PrimeFaces você pode ter tanto colunas que não são visíveis na tela mas são exportadas com o dataExporter como ter colunas que são visíveis na tela somente, não sendo exportadas.

Coluna não visível na tela mas presente no arquivo exportado:

```
<p:column style="width: 10%; display: none;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Header" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{objeto.value}" escape="false"/>
</p:column>
```

Coluna visível na tela, mas não exportada:

```
<p:column style="width: 10%;" exportable="false">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Header" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{objeto.value}" escape="false"/>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Renan, também deu certo valeu